# How to send jsonstring to httppost method in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, api, serialization, http-post

I have two controllers A(MVC controller) & B(API controller). I want to send an object from A to B.

What I did is to serialize the object into string. I just wanted to test the httppost method that is in B controller is catching the request or not.

So, I have extracted the jsonstring from action method in A and tested the httppost method in B using postman.

Here is the action method from controller A

```
public IActionResult addsonglyrics([FromForm] AddASongViewModel AddASong)
{
    string songdatatosend = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(AddASong);
    //var jsonSongData = new StringContent(songdatatosend, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var contactgetmylyricsFindSong = new HttpClient();
    contactgetmylyricsFindSong.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:65302/api/getmylyrics");
    var resultofSendSong = contactgetmylyricsFindSong.PostAsJsonAsync("addasonglyric?addmysong",songdatatosend);
    //var resultofSendSong = contactgetmylyricsFindSong.PostAsync("http://localhost:65302/api/getmylyrics/addasonglyric?addmysong",jsonSongData);
    return Ok(resultofSendSong.Result);
    //return View(addsong);
    return View(resultofSendSong.Result);
}
```

Here is the HTTP POST action method from B controller

```
public IActionResult addsonglyrics(string addmysong=null)
{
    return Ok(addmysong); // showing null at this statement

    //Do some work
}
```

tried passing

```json
{
   "lyricsmetadata":{
      "lid":0,
      "lyricsId":null,
      "lyricist":null,
      "songName":"Harima Harima",
      "songArtist":"KK, Swarnalatha",
      "songFromMovie":{
         "mid":0,
         "movieId":null,
         "movieName":"Robo",
         "director":"Shankar",
         "musicdirector":"AR Rahman",
         "dateOfRelease":"2010-06-30T00:00:00",
         "cast":null
      },
      "genre":"romance",
      "songLanguage":"Telugu",
      "LyricsOfTheSong":"addmysong"
   },
   "castLeads":{
      "cid":0,
      "castId":null,
      "actor":"Rajini",
      "actress":"Aish"
   }
}
```

this text as "text" as well as "JSON" in postman

where did I miss?

Comment: 1) Is there an error/exception of some kind 2) Are both of these controllers in the same application?

Comment: There is no error or exception, just null value and it doesn't reflect on the screen. Yes both the controllers are in same app, but I am trying to make api part as separate one.

Comment: @HarshaGangari What is the status code of the result of the `PostAsJsonAsync`?

Comment: BTW if you are using .NET 5 or 6 then you can take advantage of [`JsonContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.jsoncontent?view=net-6.0)

Comment: addasonglyric?addmysong <- addsonglyric is missing the s.
If you're in development then run Fiddler while you're posting this to check the request/response.